# If $x'(t) = x(t)^2 + t$, how can I prove $\frac{1}{1 - t} \leq x(t)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Let be $x'(t) = x(t)^2 + t$ and $x(0) = 1$ an ODE, if I assume that $x$ is a maximal solution over $]a, b[$ with $b > 0$.

I'd like to prove that $\forall t \in [0, \min(1, b)], \dfrac{1}{1 - t} \leq x(t)$ so that I can deduce $b \leq 1$ and then the solution must explode when $t \to b^{-}$.

I had multiple ideas to prove this inequality, but I'm not satisfied with my proofs.

- Proof 1: I just multiplied $(1 - t)$ and tried to prove $1 \leq (1 - t)x(t)$ by studying $\varphi : t \mapsto (1 - t)x(t)$.
- Proof 2: I tried to exploit the fact that $x'(t) \geq 1 + t$, then integrating this inequality and reinjecting it again and again might lead by careful induction $x(t) \geq \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} t^k = \dfrac{1}{1 - t}$.

Is there a more natural way to prove this?

Comment: If $y(t) = \frac{1}{1-t}$, $y$ solves $y'(t) = y^2(t)$ with $y(0) = 1$. Now by the Gronwall Lemma for the comparison of the solutions of ODEs, you have $x(t) \geq y(t)$ on $[0,1)$.

Comment: @Adri Thank you! :) — would you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Oups, sorry, too late ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
y'\ge y^2\implies -(y^{-1})'\ge 1\implies 1-\frac1{y(t)}\ge t
$$
which gives your inequality.

Using the Riccati substitution $y=-\frac{u'}u$ gives the linear ODE
$$
u''+tu=0, ~~ u(0)=1,~~u'(0)=-1.
$$
$b$ is the first positive root of $u$.
Now you can compute a power series for $u$ and try to enclose the root $b$ with roots of the partial sums.

$$
u=\sum a_nt^n\implies (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+a_{n-1}=0\\
a_0=1,~~
a_1=-1,~~
a_2=0,~~
a_3=-\frac16,~~
a_4=\frac1{12},~~
a_5=0,~~
a_6=\frac1{180},....
$$
The coefficient sequence has an alternating pattern and is falling, one can apply the Leibniz test. At the root of $1-t-\frac16t^3$ the series is positive, at the root of $1-t-\frac16t^3+\frac1{12}t^4+\frac1{180}t^5$ the series value is negative, so the root has to be in-between.